# Oracle before insert trigger that references a field in a different table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm just playing around with triggers in Oracle and need some guidance please.

I'm trying to create a trigger that prevents a customer with a nut allergy inserting or adding certain meal preferences for in a home food delivery database, but I need to reference a separate table to do this and I'm getting mixed up.

It compiles with the following error message (which means nothing to a newbie like me: P

> LS-00103: Encountered the symbol "Nuts" when expecting one of the following: not null of nan infinite dangling a empty

My tables are:

```
Customer_allergy (CustomerID, allergy)
Customer_meal_preference (CustomerID, Preference)
```

My attempt:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER AllergyCheck

BEFORE INSERT ON Customer_meal_preference 
FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
 v_CustomerAllergy VARCHAR(20);

BEGIN

SELECT CA.allergy
INTO v_CustomerAllergy
FROM Customer_allergy CA, Customer_meal_preference CP
WHERE CA.CustomerID = CP.CustomerID;


IF :new.preference = 4 AND (v_CustomerAllergy is 'Nuts') THEN RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20002, 'Customer is allergic to nuts');
     END IF;
   END AllergyCheck;
   /
```

Comment: Nothing to do with it being a trigger really. It should be `= 'Nuts'` not `is 'Nuts`.(Mildly interesting that in that context it interprets `'Nuts'` as an identifier not a string, but otherwise just a typo).

Comment: *Mildly interesting*, @Alex, is also that "customer is nuts" makes sense quite often as well :)

Comment: Also your `select into` query references the triggering table (not good in a low-level trigger) and will return more than one row. Instead, you can use `:new.customerid`.

Answer (score 0):

Adjusted code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER AllergyCheck

BEFORE INSERT ON Customer_meal_preference 
FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
 v_CustomerAllergy VARCHAR(20);
BEGIN

 SELECT CA.allergy
   INTO v_CustomerAllergy
   FROM Customer_allergy CA
        INNER JOIN Customer_meal_preference CP ON CA.CustomerID = CP.CustomerID
  WHERE CP.CustomerID = :new.CustomerID; -- for the particular customer


 IF :new.preference = 4 AND v_CustomerAllergy = 'Nuts' -- = instead of is
 THEN 
   RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20002, 'Customer is allergic to nuts');
 END IF;
END AllergyCheck;
/
```